# Ошибка при сохранении нового поля у продукта Opencart 3.0

Tags: opencart

Решил добавить новое поле `content` для продукта в opencart 3.0. Создал в таблице `oc_product` поле `content text NOT NULL`

В `/admin/model/catalog/product.php` в методе **addProduct** добавил поле следующим образом:

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET model = '" . $this->db->escape($data['model']) . "', sku = '" . $this->db->escape($data['sku']) . "', upc = '" . $this->db->escape($data['upc']) . "', ean = '" . $this->db->escape($data['ean']) . "', jan = '" . $this->db->escape($data['jan']) . "', isbn = '" . $this->db->escape($data['isbn']) . "', mpn = '" . $this->db->escape($data['mpn']) . "', content = '" . $this->db->escape($data['content']) . "', location = '" . $this->db->escape($data['location'])
```

Также в метод **editProduct**:

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET model = '" . $this->db->escape($data['model']) . "', sku = '" . $this->db->escape($data['sku']) . "', upc = '" . $this->db->escape($data['upc']) . "', ean = '" . $this->db->escape($data['ean']) . "', jan = '" . $this->db->escape($data['jan']) . "', isbn = '" . $this->db->escape($data['isbn']) . "', mpn = '" . $this->db->escape($data['mpn']) . "', content = '" . $this->db->escape($data['content']) . "', location = '" . $this->db->escape($data['location']) . "
```

Полный код не стал писать ввиду громозкости. В admin/controller/catalog/product.php

```
if (isset($this->request->post['content'])) {
            $data['content'] = $this->request->post['content'];
        } elseif (!empty($product_info)) {
            $data['content'] = $product_info['content'];
        } else {
            $data['content'] = '';
        }
```

Прописал название для поля content в локалях `en-gb` и `ru-ru`. Вьюху сделал соответствующую. Однако при сохранении валится ошибка (142 строка - метод editProduct)

```
Notice: Undefined index: content in /home/sitename/www/admin/model/catalog/product.php on line 142Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/sitename/www/admin/controller/startup/error.php:34)
```

В итоге ошибку исправил, но пришлось поменять так в `admin\view\template\catalog\product_form.twig` :

```
 <div class="form-group required">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-content{{ language.language_id }}">{{ entry_content }}</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <textarea name="product_description[{{ language.language_id }}][content]" placeholder="{{ entry_content }}" id="input-content{{ language.language_id }}" data-toggle="summernote" data-lang="{{ summernote }}" class="form-control">{{ content }}</textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Модель:

```
public function addProduct($data) {
foreach ($data['product_description'] as $language_id => $value) {
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', language_id = '" . (int)$language_id . "', name = '" . $this->db->escape($value['name']) . "', description = '" . $this->db->escape($value['description']) . "', tag = '" . $this->db->escape($value['tag']) . "', meta_title = '" . $this->db->escape($value['meta_title']) . "', meta_description = '" . $this->db->escape($value['meta_description']) . "', meta_keyword = '" . $this->db->escape($value['meta_keyword']) . "'");

            $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET content = '" . $this->db->escape($value['content']) . "' WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id ."'" );
        }
}
public function editProduct($product_id, $data) {
foreach ($data['product_description'] as $language_id => $value) {
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', language_id = '" . (int)$language_id . "', name = '" . $this->db->escape($value['name']) . "', description = '" . $this->db->escape($value['description']) . "', tag = '" . $this->db->escape($value['tag']) . "', meta_title = '" . $this->db->escape($value['meta_title']) . "', meta_description = '" . $this->db->escape($value['meta_description']) . "', meta_keyword = '" . $this->db->escape($value['meta_keyword']) . "'");

            $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET content = '" . $this->db->escape($value['content']) . "' WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id ."'" );
        }
}
```

Контроллер без изменений

Comment: Что у вас на 142 строчке, покажите.

Comment: Копайте в сторону admin/controller/catalog/product.php, скорее всего вы не правильно передаёте content. Всего кода не вижу, тяжело сказать

Comment: Все что передается в editProduct (142 строчка). В вопросе закреплено. В контроллере передавал только то, что закреплено в вопросе

Comment: Ошибка "не найден content'. Скорее всего в контроллере вы сделали что-то не так. И поэтому он не передаётся в модель.